# Earliest time to make an Eiruv Tavshilin

Tags: halacha, zemanim, eruv-tavshilin

When's the earliest time one can make an Eiruv Tavshilin on erev yom tov?

Comment: +1. Or, pushing it a bit: Using something that won't rot, can you make it on one _erev y"t_ for another _y"t_?

Answer (score 16):

With regards to the earliest you can make the Eruv on Erev Yom Tov (your actual question), The Nitei Gavriel ([Laws of Yom Tov II 81:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46543&pgnum=521)) says you can even make it the whole day, even in the morning (meaning not the night before). In the footnotes he explains none of the earlier authorities address this issue, but it appears that it is better to wait till morning. See there for more sources and information.

---

If you did do it earlier than Erev Yom Tov, he quotes The Shulchan Aruch Harav ([527:2](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh4/1/527/2)) as having said you've fulfilled your obligation (Bedi'eved), but should do it again without a blessing.

A little more depth:

The Talmud ([Beitzah 15B](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1237&size=1)) gives us two reasons why we make an Eruv Tavshillin, brought [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/563798/jewish/More-on-Eruv-Tavshilin.htm#footnoteRef3a563798):

> a) **Concern for the honor of yom tov:** This injunction impresses on people the importance of yom tov. After all, it is forbidden to prepare on yom tov even for the sake of the holy Shabbat. How much more so is it forbidden to prepare on yom tov for a following weekday!
>
> b) **Concern for the honor of Shabbat:** When Shabbat follows yom tov, there is the concern that one's attention will be focused on yom tov, which arrives first, and pay less attention to the Shabbat that follows. The eruv tavshilin compels the person to begin preparation for Shabbat even before yom tov begins, thus reminding him to reserve choice dishes for Shabbat, too.

In the Shulchan Aruch Harav ([527:2](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh4/1/527/2)), he brings practical halachic differences between the two reasons. If you want to impress on people the importance of Yom Tov, you could make the Eruv Tavshillin weeks in advance (assuming the cooked food will survive), and one Eruv could be made for many Yomim Tovim.

If however, you want to impress on people the importance of Shabbat, you must make the Eruv only on right before the holiday, and only for that holiday. Otherwise, you won't be remembering the importance of Shabbat.

Therefore, you should really only make the Eruv before Yom Tov, and only for that Yom Tov.

If you did make an Eruv a while before (intending it to cover this Yom Tov), and you forgot to make another Eruv before the Chag, you've can rely on the first Eruv you made. However, if you remember before Yom Tov you should make a new Eruv or take the old Eruv and say "With this I will be able to cook...", but don't make the blessing.

Answer (score 7):

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49150&st=&pgnum=38

Lchatchila the Eruv should be made on Erev Yom Tov - anytime starting from the night before (Orach Chaim 527:14). According to the Biur Halacha the food used in the eruv should preferably have been baked or cooked on Erev Yom Tov.

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14165&st=&pgnum=300

If it was made earlier - Lchatchila he should make another one without a Bracha on Erev Yom Tov (Orach Chaim 527:13). Bdieved it can be made earlier so long it is done with a food item that will last and it should be done without a Bracha and a Tenai (Minchas Aharon 1 Siman 145)

Comment: What Tenai must you make?

Comment: Are those seif references to the shulchan aruch? 527:13 doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: I don't understand from either answer the policy reasons for making the eruv tafshilin dafka on erev yom tov.  If I made it on Tuesday instead of Wednesday, how am I being less kovodick of either Shabbos or Yom Tov?  And does the ability to refrigerate or preserve the food (e.g. canning) for long periods make any difference?

Answer (score 5):

See the Kitzur Yalkut Yosef in [סימן תקכז - הלכות עירובי תבשילין](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0021_L2) that one should do it during the 24 hours of Erev Yom Tov.

If one does it earlier, one should redo it - but without a Bracha. However if one did not redo it, it is still valid.

He goes so far as to say one can use the Erev Tavshilin of Rosh Hashana for Sukkoth, if one had that intention; though it's not a recommended practice.

> **ה** לכתחלה צריך להניח העירוב דוקא **מליל ערב יום טוב עד שקיעת החמה של ערב יום טוב**. ואם **הניחו קודם ערב יום טוב, יחזור ויטלנו בערב יום טוב** ויאמר שהוא סומך עליו לשם מצות עירוב, לאפות ולבשל מיום טוב לשבת. (ולא יברך עליו), ומיהו אם **לא עשה כן, בכל זאת מותר לו לאפות ולבשל** על סמך העירוב הזה. [ילקוט יוסף על המועדים עמוד תצו].‏
>
> **ו** וכן אם הניח עירוב על דעת **לסמוך עליו גם ליום טוב אחר**, כגון ראש השנה שחל ביום חמישי וששי, ומתכוין בשעת הנחת העירוב לסמוך עליו בחג הסוכות שחל גם כן בחמישי וששי בחו"ל, או שמניח העירוב בערב חג הסוכות ומתכוין לסמוך עליו בשמחת תורה, **לכתחלה לא יסמוך עליו ביום טוב האחר**, כי **יש פוסקים הסוברים שאפילו אם הניח העירוב שנים או שלשה ימים מקודם לא מהני**, הילכך לכתחלה צריך לעשות עירוב אחר, ביום טוב האחר, ויברך עליו, או שיטול את העירוב של יום טוב הראשון ויאמר עליו: "בהדין עירובא יהא שרי לנא לאפויי ולבשולי" וכו', ולא יברך עליו. אבל **בדיעבד יכול לסמוך עליו כל זמן שהוא קיים** וראוי לאכילה. [חזון עובדיה על הלכות יום טוב, דין עירובי תבשילין].‏